# Regex which invalidates a combination of digits, hyphens(-) and/or dots(.)

Tags: regex

Currently I have a regex to validate letters, digits, hyphens and/or dots.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-\\.]?[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

That makes these values valid:

```
"john.doe"
"john123"
"johndoe"
"john-doe"
"john-doe.123"
```

What I need in addition is *rejecting* values that only contain a combination of digits, hyphens or/and dots. Meaning the value has to have at least one letter to be valid.

This includes:

```
"123"
"1.2.3"
"1-2-3"
"12.3"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Actually the regex you posted is at least missing a `*` just before the `$`. Otherwise it won't match some of your examples.

Comment: There is no law that says you may only use one regular expression.  In many cases it is best to have two easily understood regexes (in your case, one to check for validity and another to check for invalidity) rather than making one convoluted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
/^(?:[0-9][-\.]?)*[A-Za-z](?:[-\.]?[A-Za-z0-9])*$/
```

- Enforces at least one letter
- Allows hyphens and dots only to be followed by digits or letters
- Doesn't allow hyphens or dots at beginning or end

([Regexr](http://regexr.com?33gpc))